# C++ make an object whose type is an abstract class

Tags: c++, abstract-class, pure-virtual

I am trying to make a system like Java's [`swing`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/start/about.html), where you have a window, and that window has multiple components, such as Labels (text/images), Text Boxes, Check Boxes, etc. The way `swing` works is that there is a `Component` class, which is abstract, which has an abstract paint method, which draws the component, and some other methods. The actual window (`JFrame`) has a list (of sorts) of all of the components in the window. These components' actual types are unknown, but they all extend the `Component` class.

My `Window` class:

```cpp
class Window {
public:
    ...
    template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Component, T>::value>::type* = nullptr> T addComponent(T component);
private:
    ...
    std::vector<Component> components;
    ...
};
```

`Component`:

```cpp
class Component {
public:
    ...
    virtual void paintComponent() = 0;
    ...
};
```

Somewhere along the line, this code is called:

```cpp
for each (Component c in components) {
    c.paintComponent();
}
```

However, I cannot make an object of type `Component`, because it is abstract, although the actual objects would be other types that *extend* `Component` and have their own `paintComponent()` method. For methods (`Window::addComponent()`), I can use

```cpp
template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Component, T>::value>::type* = nullptr> T
```

however, this does not work for variables.

So, my question is, **How do I make an object of an abstract type**, i.e. how do I make a `Component` object (or an object that extends Component, but whose actual type is unknown)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't make an object of abstract type. Are you asking how to implement `instanceof` in C++? If so, check out `dynamic_cast`. (As a side-issue, have you looked into existing cross-platform C++ widget toolkits like Qt and wx-widgets?)

Comment: @Andy Sorry is I wasn't clear on this, I want to make an object that extends an abstract type, but whose actual type is unknown.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't instantiate a type of a abstract class. You have to refer to it through a pointer. This will force you to do manual memory management. So using a smart pointer like [`shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) or [`unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) can help reduce headaches. Using pointers would make your vector look like this

```
std::vector<Component*> components;
//                   ^ Indicates pointer
```

and then in your loop you would call it like this

```
p->paintComponent();
```

This way you can use `Component` for any type that derives from it.

Also, if Component is going to be used like this it should have a virtual destructor. This will make sure that the correct destructor is called if it deleted through a pointer to a `Component`. This would make the destructor declaration look like this

```
virtual ~Component() { }
```

Answer (score 1):

In systems like that, types like *Label*, *CheckBox*, *TextBox* are separate classes derived from *Component* class. So, if you want a similar behavior, you need to implement new classes and derive them from *Component* class. You are also required to override the virtual functions.